# Assign zip code owner to the lead

Tags: trigger

I have two object one is lead and another zipcode(fields default owner and zip code field).when I create a record in a lead page it would search through zipcode in zip code object in a zip code field and need to update that ownerId to the lead owner .please anyone help me I don't know where I am wrong and getting error

```
trigger updatelead on Lead (before insert)
{
    for (lead l : Trigger.new)
    {
        if (lead.PostalCode != null)
        {
            List<zipcode__c> zip = [select ownerId from zipcode__c where zipcode__c=:lead.postalcode] \\getting error 
            {
                if (zip.size() > 0)
                {
                    Lead.ownerid = zip[0].ownerId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me where I am wrong

Comment: Hi Akanksha, I've marked this question as an exact duplicate of the linked question, as the answer is essentially the same problem; you're using the wrong variable name in three places (5,7, and 11); it should be `l` instead of `lead`. As Renato stated, though, you also need to bulkify your code. Please read that answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted I assume you are getting a `System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101` error.

This is happening because you are issuing a query command at line 7 inside a loop (defined on line 3). You need to **[bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code)** your trigger code, like the following:

```
trigger updatelead on Lead (before insert) {
    // best practice tip: always set up conditions
    // for your trigger. This will help you lots when
    // you need to update the code on the future
    // (in case you need to create another contexts,
    // like update or delete on the object)
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
        List<String> zipcodes = new List<String>();
        // get all zipcodes first
        for (Lead record : Trigger.new) {
            if (record.PostalCode != null) {
                zipcodes.add(record.PostalCode);
            }
        }
        // issue just one query statement in your code to get all zip codes
        List<ZipCode__c> codes = [SELECT OwnerId, ZipCode__c FROM ZipCode__c WHERE ZipCode__c IN :zipcodes];

        // iterate again your trigger records
        for (Lead record : Trigger.new) {
            if (lead.PostalCode != null) {
                // if the Lead has a zipcode, then iterate the previously queried
                // records. If it finds a match, then assign the zipcode owner
                // to the lead record.
                for (ZipCode__c zc : codes) {
                    if (record.PostalCode == zc.ZipCode__c) {
                        record.OwnerId = zc.OwnerId;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While you are correct that they shouldn't be using a SOQL in a loop, that's not actually the error they're talking about; they haven't gotten as far as even compiling the code.

Comment: Can anyone let me know how can I do above requirement using visualworkflow